# Distance to a straight line in standard form

Tags: geometry

For a 3D straight line expressed in the standard form

```
a1*x + b1*y + c1*z + d1 = 0
a2*x + b2*y + c2*z + d2 = 0
```

and a given point `x0,y0,z0`

what is the distance from the point to the straight line?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math related problem, rather than a programming issue. Look, for example, at the first result of a Google search about this topic: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Distance from point **P0** to parametric line **L**(t) = **Base** + t * **Dir** is

```
Dist = Length(CrossProduct(Dir, P0 - Base)) / Length(Dir)
```

To find direction vector:

```
Dir = CrossProduct((a1,b1,c1), (a2,b2,c2))
```

To get some arbitrary base point, solve equation system with 2 equations and three unknowns (find arbitrary solution):

```
a1*x + b1*y + c1*z + d1 = 0
a2*x + b2*y + c2*z + d2 = 0
```

Check minors consisting of a and b, a and c, b and c coefficients. When minor is non-zero, corresponding variable might be taken as free one. For example, if `a1 * b2 - b1 * a2 <> 0`, choose variable `z`  as free - make it zero or another value and solve system for two unknowns x and y.

(I omitted extra cases of parallel or coinciding planes)